# Quise abrir el servidor localhost:3000 de un nuevo proyecto de React y me aparece un error "Failed to compile"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost

La cuestión es que recién había empezado el nuevo proyecto en react y no he tocado nada del código.

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
Failed to compile
./src/index.js 1:82
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:82)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> $RefreshRuntime$ = require('C:/Users/josu y axel/Desktop/Axel/Development Project's/pagina_con_react/pagina_react/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js');
| $RefreshSetup$(module.id);
|
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que intentes reinstalar/Actualizar Node.js. Luego reinicias tu servidor.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```